# How to Record Streaming Video?

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-recording

I am able to play a **Streaming video** with http server connection in a `SurfaceView`. And I was creating `ContextMenu` for recording the video by adding menu items **StartRecording** and **StopRecording**. But am able record a Camera Video by calling `mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);`

Here I want to set Video Source as Streaming Video Source. Is there any possibility for doing this?

But I want to record the Streaming Video while it is playing. Can you please tell me how to do record while it is playing?

Will you please provide any sample code for this problem?

My sample code shown below:

**main.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"             android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/frameLayoutRoot">

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceViewFrame" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></SurfaceView>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMediaController" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@color/media_controller_bg_color">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textViewPlayed" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/media_controller_text_color" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="0:00:00" android:padding="0dp" android:textSize="13sp" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

        <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBarProgress" android:layout_weight="1" style="@style/MyCustomProgressStyle" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:progress="50"></SeekBar>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textViewLength" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/media_controller_text_color" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="0:00:00" android:textSize="13sp" android:padding="0dp" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarWait"></ProgressBar>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageViewPauseIndicator" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/pause_button"></ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**MediaPlayerDemo.java:**

```
public class MediaPlayerDemo_Video extends Activity implements
    OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener,       OnClickListener, OnSeekCompleteListener,
    Callback, OnSeekBarChangeListener, AnimationListener {

private String path2 = "http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";
private String path = "";

    private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerDemo";
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView surfaceViewFrame;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
// private String path;
private Bundle extras;
private Animation hideMediaController;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutMediaController;
private SeekBar seekBarProgress;
private TextView textViewPlayed;
private TextView textViewLength;
private ProgressBar progressBarWait;
private ImageView imageViewPauseIndicator;
private Timer updateTimer;
AudioManager volume;
int keyCode = 0;
   KeyEvent keyEvent;
   private MediaRecorder mVideoRecorder = null;
   private Camera mCamera;

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer_2);

    linearLayoutMediaController = (LinearLayout)       findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMediaController);
    linearLayoutMediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        hideMediaController =       AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MediaPlayerDemo_Video.this, R.anim.disapearing);
    hideMediaController.setAnimationListener(this);

    imageViewPauseIndicator = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPauseIndicator);
    imageViewPauseIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    textViewPlayed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPlayed);
    textViewLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLength);

    surfaceViewFrame = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewFrame);
    surfaceViewFrame.setOnClickListener(this);
    surfaceViewFrame.setClickable(false);

    seekBarProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarProgress);
    seekBarProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
             //     seekBarProgress.setProgress(0);

    progressBarWait = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarWait);
    volume = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = volume.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume = volume.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    seekBarProgress.setMax(maxVolume);
    seekBarProgress.setProgress(curVolume);

    surfaceHolder = surfaceViewFrame.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            imageViewPauseIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
 }

 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "StartRecording");
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "StopRecording");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:

        if (mediaRecorder == null)
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); // Works well

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

                             mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);  
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/StreamLive.3gp");
     mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(-1);
     try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    case 1:
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}   

      private void playVideo() {
         try {
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                    try {
                        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                                    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
    playVideo();
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    Log.i(TAG, "========== onPrepared ===========");
    int duration = mediaplayer.getDuration() / 1000; // duration in seconds
    seekBarProgress.setMax(duration);
    textViewLength.setText(Utils.durationInSecondsToString(duration));
    progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    // Get the dimensions of the video
            int videoWidth = mMediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
            int videoHeight = mMediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
            float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float)       videoHeight;
            Log.i(TAG, "VIDEO SIZES: W: " + videoWidth + " H: " +        videoHeight + " PROP: " + videoProportion);

            // Get the width of the screen
            int screenWidth =            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int screenHeight =            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
            float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth /     (float)       screenHeight;
            Log.i(TAG, "VIDEO SIZES: W: " + screenWidth + " H: " +     screenHeight + " PROP: " + screenProportion);

            // Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp =        surfaceViewFrame.getLayoutParams();

            if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
                lp.width = screenWidth;
                lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth /     videoProportion);
            } else {
                lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float)     screenHeight);
                lp.height = screenHeight;
            }

            // Commit the layout parameters
            surfaceViewFrame.setLayoutParams(lp);

            // Start video
            if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                updateMediaProgress();
                     linearLayoutMediaController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                hideMediaController();

            }
            surfaceViewFrame.setClickable(true);
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
    mp.stop();
    if (updateTimer != null) {
        updateTimer.cancel();
    }
     //     mp.seekTo(0);
     //     finish();
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);
    int progress = (int) ((float) mp.getDuration() * ((float) percent /        (float) 100));
    seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(progress / 1000);

   } 
}
```

Comment: did u find how to record video while it is playing as am also looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is like what I faced with record streaming audio on android..
You can try write video header(depends on your video format) to stream and append data when buffer updated..flush stream to wherever you want to..
Check out how RehearsalAudioRecorder works.